# Spaces in Command Line Arguments

Tags: java, string, arguments

I am doing an assignment for university and I have a quick question regarding command line arguments and spaces.

I have to find an image file which will be given to us in the command line. I am trying to run my program but because my file location has spaces in the folder names, java assumes that there is more than one argument.

Therefore when I assign `args[0]` to the `String` it stops half way through because of the spaces.

Is there a way to just take everything from the command line and assign it to a `String`?

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Awesome...quotes worked perfectly...Thanks

Answer (score 10):

Just use quotes:

```
java -jar MyThing.jar "My File Name with loads of spaces.jpg"
```

Quick demo:

```
public static void main(final String[] args) throws Exception {   
    Stream.of(args).forEach(System.out::println);
}
```

Output:

```
java -jar MyThing.jar My File Name with loads of spaces.jpg
My
File
Name
with
loads
of
spaces.jpg

java -jar MyThing.jar "My File Name with loads of spaces.jpg"
My File Name with loads of spaces.jpg
```

Answer (score 1):

The system interprets the space character as a separator for command line arguments. If you want the argument with spaces you would join them with double quotes.

```
% java test.class "Java is escaped"
Java is escaped
```

Answer (score 0):

If you select one or more files in File Explorer and run an app from RMB the arguments to app should be the files selected. But if the folder in question contains spaces, you're stuck! No way to add double quotes!
Microsoft bug?

Comment: This post doesn't look like an attempt to answer this question. Every post here is expected to be an explicit attempt to *answer* this question; if you have a critique or need a clarification of the question or another answer, you can [post a comment](/help/privileges/comment) (like this one) directly below it. Please remove this answer and create either a comment or a new question. See: [Ask questions, get answers, no distractions](/tour)